# HTML UTF-8 code messes up

Tags: html, css, utf-8

I just did a simple update within my index.html only added some texts and did not do anything else with the code. When I uploaded it everything is a mess.

I uploaded the English site and other pages and everything is ok. Other pages I updated worked ok. Check here: http://hallfjallet.se/indexeng.html

When I uploaded the Swedish site (the html page I did the updates) which always worked well before, somehow the utf code messed up - but I haven't done anything with it. (See the site in Swedish here :  http://hallfjallet.se/ )

All I did was to use Filezilla to upload via FTP.

My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7">
    <title>
        Hållfjällets turiststation
    </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./Hållfjällets turiststation_files/default.css" media="screen">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./Hållfjällets turiststation_files/prettyPhoto.css" media="screen">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./Hållfjällets turiststation_files/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./Hållfjällets turiststation_files/core.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./Hållfjällets turiststation_files/jquery.pngFix.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./Hållfjällets turiststation_files/jquery.prettyPhoto.js"></script>
    <!--[if IE 6]>
    <style>
        #pitch .infoline {margin-top:-74px;}
        .post-options {margin:-55px 0 40px 138px;}
    </style>
    <![endif]-->

</head>
<body>

<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/sv_SE/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.0";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

   <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="logo">
            <img src="./Hållfjällets turiststation_files/hallfjallet.png" alt="Hållfjället">
        </div>

        <div id="content">
        <!-- main menu -->
            <ul class="menu" id="jMenu">

                    <li class="current.remove"><a href="index.html">Hem</a></li>
                    <li><a href="historia.html">Historia</a></li>
                    <li><a href="prislista.pdf">Prislista</a></li>
                    <li><a href="lunchmeny.html">Lunchmeny</a></li>
                    <li><a href="kontakt.html">Kontakta oss</a></li>


                <li><a id="ctl00_hlLanguage" href="indexeng.html"><img src="./Hållfjällets turiststation_files/us.png" alt="In English"> In English</a></li>
            </ul>

            <div class="x"></div>

            <!-- image slider -->
            <div id="pitch">
                <div class="pitch-gallery">
                    <div class="pitch-gallery-holder" id="gallery-pitch-holder" style="left: 0px;">

                            <div class="pitch-gallery-div">
                                <img src="./Hållfjällets turiststation_files/3.jpg" alt="Pitch 1" style="">
                                <div class="infoline">Hållfjällets turiststation</div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="pitch-gallery-div">
                                <img src="./Hållfjällets turiststation_files/17.jpg" alt="Pitch 2">
                                <div class="infoline">...</div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="pitch-gallery-div">
                                <img src="./Hållfjällets turiststation_files/1.jpg" alt="Pitch 3">
                                <div class="infoline">...</div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="pitch-gallery-div">
                                <img src="./Hållfjällets turiststation_files/7.jpg" alt="Pitch 4">
                                <div class="infoline">...</div>
                            </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- main content -->
            <div id="left">

    <!-- Svenska -->

    <h1>Hej!</h1>
    <p>Hållfjället har nya ägare, men fortsätter att vara samma unika idyll som vanligt.
         Vi öppnar den 1:a Februari - 2015 och kommer att hålla öppet under hela säsongen.
     Bokningar för säsongen kan göras på telefon 0706-859710 eller 0647-340 49.<br/>
        <img src = "./Kontakta oss_files/owners.jpg"width="600" height="400" border = "0"> 
         Vårt föreståndarpar Kjell och Majli hälser er välkomna. 


    <br clear="both">
    <hr>
    <br clear="both">

        <h1>För dig som vill uppleva något annorlunda</h1>
        <p>Tänk dig att efter en stärkande skön sömn, vakna och upptäcka att solen lyser från en klarblå himmel. Efter en snabb uppstigning så väntar en näringsrik "Hållfjälls¬frukost", en bra början på en dag ute på fjället. I samband med frukosten så gör du ditt eget smörgåspaket och hämtar din termos som är fylld med varm choklad, kaffe eller varför inte med kall "Hållfjällssaft".</p>
        <p>Tillsammans med din familj eller kompisar, så tar ni på er skidorna direkt utanför bron och åker ut på dagens skidtur. Turen startar direkt med skön och härlig skidåkning, inget slitsamt klättrande för att komma upp på fjället här inte, du startar ju direkt på kalfjället.</p>
        <p>Efter ett par timmars skidåkning så är det dags för välbehövlig rast, och ni letar upp en plats som ligger lite i lä för vinden. Om solen fortfarande är framme så blir rasten extra njutbar och ni kanske vill ta långrast, sitta eller ligga och känna hur solens varma strålar bättrar på solbrännan.
Ett annat förslag kan vara att testa fjällfiske i någon av områdets sjöar.( Då behöver du fiskekort) .</p>
        <p>Framåt fyra-fem tiden så känns det bra att se Hållfjället ligga i solskenet, och den sista biten hem blir extra lättåkt, kanske även "först hem får pris". Efter att du har duschat, så känns det skönt att slappa en stund.</p>
        <p>Klockan 18.00 är det så dags för middag i matsalen, där såväl brasan i öppna spisen som de tända ljusen ger en intim och festlig stämning. Middagen består alltid av tre rätter; förrätt, varmrätt och dessert. Hållfjällets matsedel, som bygger på husmanskost, brukar vara mycket uppskattad av gästerna.</p>
        <p>Efter maten så erbjuder Hållfjället möjligheter till samvaro mellan gästerna på sätt som man själva bestämmer. Någon TV finns inte och det är medvetet, därför att under vistelsen på Hållfjället ska man kunna koppla av "världen utanför", och slippa matas med det eländes elände som TV och övriga massmedia lever på. Självklart så finns det möjligheter att ordna olika arrangemang, om gästerna så vill.</p>
        <p>Om det är stjärnklart och eller månsken, så kan du på Hållfjället uppleva en vinterhimmel som ingen annanstans. Att stå ute på bron och titta på en stjärnhimmel som inte störs av det ljussken som finns i vanliga fall, är en sak man minns länge. Om dessutom norrskenet flammar, då är det bara kylan utomhus som får dig att gå in i värmen igen.</p>
        <p><b> OBS Vi är alkoholfria</b></p>

    <!-- Engelska -->


            </div>

            <!-- sidebar -->
            <div id="right">
    <!-- Svenska -->

        <h2> Gilla oss på facebook</h2>
        <div class="fb-like-box" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/hallfjallet" data-width="200" data-height="150" data-colorscheme="light" data-show-faces="true" data-header="true" data-stream="false" data-show-border="true"></div>
        <hr>
    <br clear="both">
        <h2>Nyheter</h2>
        <img src= "./Hållfjällets turiststation_files/sidbild2.jpg" "width = 200" height = "150">
        <br>Nu hyr vi ut fullt utrustad sportstuga i anslutning till hotellet. För mer info, se prislistan.<br>
<br>

        <hr>
        <img src="./Hållfjällets turiststation_files/newspaper.png" alt="Skrivet om Hållfjället" style="float: right">
        <h2>Vad andra skriver om Hållfjället</h2>

    <!-- Engelska -->

    <p><b><a href="http://www.dn.se/resor/sverige/pa-hallfjallet-gar-tiden-lite-langsammare-1.153555" target="_blank">» På Hållfjället går tiden lite långsammare</a></b><br>
    Dagens Nyheter (extern länk)</p>
    <p><b><a href="http://www.sodraarefjallen.com/ovrigt.php?id=ovrigt" target="_blank">» Hotellet utan el i väglöst land</a></b><br>
    Södra Årefjällen (external länk)</p>
    <p><b><a href="http://www.alltomresor.se/guider/aor%209_06%20Fjallen.pdf" target="_blank">Hållfjället - strömlös 50-talsnostalgi</a></b><br>
    Allt om resor (extern länk)</p>
    <img src="./Hållfjällets turiststation_files/Det Goda Livet.png" alt="De goda livet i Jämtland och Härjdalen" style="float: right">
    <p><b><a href="http://www.adlibris.com/se/product.aspx?isbn=9188672263" target="_blank">» Det goda livet i Jämtland och Härjedalen</a></b></p>
    <p>Prisbelönad bok av bl&nbsp;a Tage Levin och Ulla Tham. Hållfjällets bidrag till boken är dess berömda trattkantarellsoppa och hjortronparfait.</p>

            </div>
            <div class="x"></div>
            <!-- <div class="break"></div> -->
            <!-- small posts -->
            <div id="feature">


            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- footer -->
        <div id="footer">
            <div style="width: 33%; float: left">
                <p>Hållfjällets turiststation<br>Ottsjö<br>830 10 Undersåker</p>
            </div>
            <div style="width: 32%; float: left; text-align: center">
                <p>Tel: +46 706-85 97 10 (Magnus Olsson)<br/>
                0647-340 49 (Hållfjällets turiststation under öppettider)<br/>
                Tillfällig epost: magnus.olsson@stromsslott.se</p>
            </div>
            <div style="width: 33%; float: left; text-align: right">
                <p>Bankgiro: 660-5505</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- gallery starter and prettyPhoto starter -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jGallery('pitch');
        $(document).pngFix();
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto();
        });
    </script>



<div class="pp_overlay" style="opacity: 0; height: 1842px; display: none; width: 1349px;"></div><div class="pp_pic_holder" style="top: 276.5px; left: 624.5px;"><div class="pp_top"><div class="pp_left"></div><div class="pp_middle"></div><div class="pp_right"></div></div><div class="pp_content"><a href="http://www.hallfjallet.se/#" class="pp_expand" title="Expand the image">Expand</a><div class="pp_loaderIcon"></div><div class="pp_hoverContainer" style="margin-left: 20px;"><a class="pp_next" href="http://www.hallfjallet.se/#">next</a><a class="pp_previous" href="http://www.hallfjallet.se/#">previous</a></div><div id="pp_full_res"></div><div class="pp_details clearfix"><a class="pp_close" href="http://www.hallfjallet.se/#">Close</a><p class="pp_description"></p><div class="pp_nav"><a href="http://www.hallfjallet.se/#" class="pp_arrow_previous">Previous</a><p class="currentTextHolder">0/0</p><a href="http://www.hallfjallet.se/#" class="pp_arrow_next">Next</a></div></div></div><div class="pp_bottom"><div class="pp_left"></div><div class="pp_middle"></div><div class="pp_right"></div></div></div><div class="ppt" style="top: 276.5px; left: 644.5px;"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Recommend simplifying your question (be more explicit) and your code example: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Having a bit of trouble understanding the question and its relation to the code you provided.

Comment: maybe the upload got corrupted, have you tried uploading again ? What about uploading via your file Manager ? If you haven't done anything with it this is the most likely problem

Comment: yeh I uploaded several times and several files but only the index.html messus up. I edited in several files aswell and they all work well on the site

Comment: Never ever use "strange" characters (which may be escaped) in file/folder name.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your resources (css, js, jpg, and a total of 17 files) are not loading (404 not found) because of differences in encoding.

The UTF-8 document contains links encoded like this:

```
./H�llfj�llets turiststation_files/default.css
```

which **incorrectly** refers to

```
http://hallfjallet.se/H%EF%BF%BDllfj%EF%BF%BDllets%20turiststation_files/default.css
```

*Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)* [image: screenshot of errors]

whereas the English document contains links encoded like this:

```
href="./Hållfjällets turiststation_files/default.css"
```

which **correctly** refers to

```
http://hallfjallet.se/H%C3%A5llfj%C3%A4llets%20turiststation_files/default.css
```

One suggestion is that you can copy the encoded link given by your browser for each resource (Cntrl+Shift+i) and use it.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by doing the following. 
Taking and .html file that worked and moved only the breadtect there.
THen I updated it again and it worked.
I dont know why.

Comment: Sounds great! For the humor https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-ATSJczO04qU/VJh223yTktI/AAAAAAAAHMk/O3EoMoVfSeA/s426/i_love_non_ascii.jpg